# change string to date format in a column using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, datetime

I have a dataset called main, and a column called Service.Start.Date which I want to format as dd/mm/yyyy.

```
import os
path = 'C:/Users/xxx/Documents'
main = open ('main.csv','w')
import datetime

datetime.datetime.strptime(main.'Service.Start.Date', '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%m/%d/%y)
```

and I get invalid syntax. I have never used Python, I am trying to make sense of it and spent two hours already.

Comment: for one thing: you're missing the ending quote on the `strftime` call

Comment: and accessing the column is wonky. take a look at this [beginner's guide](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/using-the-csv-module-in-python/)

Comment: `main.'Service.Start.Date'` doesn't make sense. `main` is a file, open in write mode. Whatever you were planning to read from that file is probably already gone. This is tough to answer as there are a number of errors in your code. Do you have an example of `main.csv` contents?

Comment: It is good practice to use the `with` keyword when dealing with file objects.

Comment: If two hours is *all* you have spent learning Python, then the answer to your question is that you need to spend even more time learning Python.  There is so much wrong with your code already, spending some more time in beginner tutorials will help you much more than we can here.

Comment: Ref   Service.Start.Date   Service.End.Date      
123   01/06/2015               31/03/2016                        


import csv
import sys
from datetime import datetime
FIELD = 7
FMT = '%m/%d/%Y'

with open('C:/Users/lhull/Documents/main.csv') as csvfile:
    readablefile = csv.reader(sys.stdin)
    writablefile = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
    for row in readablefile:
        dt = datetime.strptime(row[FIELD], FMT)
        row[FIELD] = dt.isoformat()
        writablefile.writerow(row)

cat C:/Users/lhull/Documents/main.csv | python fixdate.py > another_file.csv